# ScollView after Style change not on top

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, scrollview

I've an Splash screen with no actionbar. Then I switch to an activity with a fragment and a ScrollView. But every time I start it, it is not on top.

I solved it with this in onCreate:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // workaround for style change
        // action bar visible change
        ((ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollView)).smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Now it scrolls every time on start on top. But if I change fragments I don't want it. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to scroll to the top of the ScrollView programmatically?

Comment: it can also be done by XML - I want the the ListView starts on top || there are problems during creating it so it "starts on top", but then the actionbar overlaps it